# PHP/ffmpeg (Windows 7): - Permission Denied. Tried everything, but still doesn't work

Tags: php, ffmpeg, windows-7-x64, permission-denied

I have a command-line PHP script that, when given the folder name as an argument when executing the script, will find all images in said folder and resize them using FFmpeg. Problem is, I always get a Permission Denied error in FFmpeg when it attempts to get at the files within the folder. This is while being on Windows 7.

The big problem is that I've tried every solution that keeps popping up on the interwebs when I search for how to fix it. I've changed the settings in Avast!, did the attrib command (both as normal and "Run as Administrator") to unmark as read-only, took ownership of the folder both via command line and using that GUI takeown context menu thing everyone keeps throwing around (obviously before my efforts to mark everything as not-read-only), messed with permissions, *everything*. I keep searching and searching for a solution, but all of the sites keep throwing out the same things over and over again - things that I've already tried multiple times. I'm at the end of my rope here. All I want to do is resize images quickly and automatically so I can put them up on my website, yet this has been a massive headache...

Please help me! :(

**Update (Additional Points):**

- The error is through FFmpeg, not PHP. FFmpeg spits out the permission denied error, the script just continues doing what it does normally (or, at least, it would if it weren't for my die statement that kicks in in the event of FFmpeg failing).
- FFmpeg will execute just fine if it's run normally through the command line instead of through the script. However, this does not help the problem of me having to resize hundreds of photos by hand!
- I'm just running this script in the normal terminal using the CLI engine. Weird use for PHP, I know, but since I already knew how to work with FFmpeg in PHP (but in Linux!) so I figured I might as well use the code as a normal, stand-alone program...
- FFmpeg spits out the same error regardless of which PHP function is used to execute it. It happens for shell_exec, exec, passthru, and system.

Comment: Please provide the command line that you're using?

Comment: Clearly *everything* hasn't been tried. Did you just copy all stuff to the system Temp directory e.g.? Did you assign ownership to yourself, perhaps, not the Apache process? What exact message appeared in the PHP, Apache or system logs? And did you try not using Windows?

Comment: Not using Windows would be absolutely different story! Even using another compilation is another story. Like I said below, I think this is the error in FFMpeg compilation - I have encountered it before.

Comment: YAY the site isn't read-only again!

@Ilia: I don't know what you're referring to by "command line", soooo:
- The command used to execute the script is php resizer.php [foldername], in this case "Starbucks"
- The command used to execute FFmpeg within the script is "ffmpeg -i " . $full . " -s " . $temp . "x" . $temp2 . " " . $folder . "/temp/" . $iteration . ".png";, where $full is the file location of the image, $temp and $temp2 are the width and height of the image, respectively, $folder is the folder given at script execution, and $iteration is the iteration of the loop that this line is in.

Comment: @mario: The folder and scripts in question are on my D:/ drive, not my C:/ drive (my computer has two physical hard drives - I use one for OSs and one for file storage). I assigned ownership to myself, and I'm not doing this through any internet or server processes - I use the PHP script in the standard command line terminal to pull this off. PHP doesn't output any errors, FFmpeg does - it gives me a [foldername]/.: Permission Denied and then nothing else happens. I have not tried booting into Linux for this script yet, I have issues due to my NVidia graphics card. :(

Comment: I was getting a similar error, but my problem was that I was passing a folder name instead of a filename to ffmpeg as the input.

Answer (score 1):

I can remember having the same issue and I would recommend you to start from checking other compilations of FFMpeg for Windows. I used one of the following and they worked perfectly! Please go [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)  and then let us know if it solves your problem. I used 64-bit Builds (Static) version! Not all compilations of FFMpeg for Windows are the same! If it is still not working let us see the error log and the command line that you're using! Though I think everything should be fine!

On the other hand you can simplify everything and try to use [Mogrify Utility](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html) that works as simple as that:

```
 mogrify -resize 640×480 *.jpg
```

I can confirm that I used it as well instead of FFMpeg. Just install the tool and change the command line in your script and that is it! It will use less resources than FFMpeg most likely and provide you with the same result!

All the best, Ilia.

Comment: The build I'm using is indeed the 64-bit Windows static build of FFmpeg from that site. :) It could be a problem with FFmpeg? My interest is piqued. Pretty much all the sites I've been to have stated that it's a Windows permissions problem, so I haven't tried much in the way of messing with FFmpeg builds.

Comment: Try to check PHP settings, such as open_basedir for example. Make sure you have proper permissions on the temporary folders which should be full access read and write. (0777 Unix Type). Also try to change tmp directory of where PHP stores temporary files to your script directory?

Comment: Or try to use Mogrify Utility which I described in the edited post above!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by opening the command prompt as administrator. This is achieved by highlighting the command prompt file name and opening with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Answer (score -1):

See this URL :-

http://forum.serviio.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=960

**Read This**

Assuming that ffmpeg running from Windows Service needs to access files on a network server, you need to be sure that the service user account has sufficient network permissions.

If both computers are in the same Windows domain, then you can run the services under a domain account and add permissions to access the network share from this account.

Alternatively, you can allow Everyone to access the network share and edit Local Security Policy to enable Network Access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users.